# Changing JButton background colour temporarily?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm super new to Java, and in need of some help. 
I'm making a little java desktop application where I basically have a grid of 4 JButtons ( 2 x 2 grid), and I need the background colour of individual JButtons to change, and after one second, change back to the original colour (the game I'm trying to make is like Simon, where you have to follow a pattern of buttons that light up). 
I have a vector that contains randomly generated numbers in the range of 1 to 4, and I want to be able to get each element from the vector and get the corresponding button to change to a different colour for one second (for example, if the vector contains 2 4 1, I would want button 2 to change, then button 4 to change, then button 1 to change).

Is this possible or is there a better way to go about doing this with something other than JButtons? How do I implement this?

Also, I'm running Mac OS X, which apparently (based on some things I've read on forums) doesn't like JButtons background changing (I think it's because of system look and feel), how can I change this so it works on mac?

Thank you in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to extend [`JToggleButton`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JToggleButton.html) and override `paintComponent()` to display the color. A `javax.swing.Timer` can control timing. Here is a somewhat more elaborate [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/buttons).

```
private static class SimonButton extends JToggleButton {

    private final Color color;
    Dimension size = new Dimension(100, 100);

    public SimonButton(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (this.isSelected()) {
            g.setColor(color);
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.lightGray);
        }
        g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return size;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `paintComponent()` override works for Windows 8 too (to get another JButton background color), where other solutions fail.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use the setBackground(...) method to set the Color and then use a Swing Timer to reset the background when it fires.

Edit:

If your problem is that the setBackground() method doesn't work on some LAF's, then you could add an Icon to the button that is simply a solid Color. Then to change the background color you simple change the Icon.

Comment: Yep, `com.apple.laf.AquaButtonUI` is recalcitrant. I sometimes implement `Icon` and do `setIcon(this)`, drawing in `paintIcon()` instead of `paintComponent().

Answer (score 2):

For your purposes, you don't necessarily have to use a `JButton`.  You can use `JLabels` or `JPanels`.

During initialization, you can `setBackground()` on each one to set its color, and add a `MouseListener` to each one to detect a click.

To flash the Simon pattern, create a `javax.swing.Timer` that fires once every second.  (You may want to make the delay configurable if 1 second seems like a long time.)  For simplicity, the timer could `setOpaque(false)` on all the `JLabels`, then `setOpaque(true)` on the `JLabel` whose color you want to flash.  Note that you might want to wait until the next timer iteration before doing `setOpaque(true)`, so the flashes don't run together if you want to flash the same `JLabel` multiple times in a row.

The advantage of using `setOpaque()` is that you can set the `MouseListener` to just call `setOpaque(true)` on press and `setOpaque(false)` on release, and check whether the correct `JLabel` was clicked, without having to repeatedly recompute which color should be used for a given `JLabel`.

Comment: This is the right way to go but you should use javax.swing.Timer rather than TimerTask as the setOpaque call should be made on the EDT.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, Russ; I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
okJButton = new JButton() {
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.decode("0X123456"));
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
}
};
okJButton.setForeground(Color.white);
okJButton.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.white, 1));
```